# Function to Function get variable array

Tags: php

look below code:

```
$myvar = array();

first();

function first()
{
    global $myvar;

    $array(apple, banana, orange);
}

second();

function second()
{
    global $myvar;

    print_r($array);
}
```

then in output, second function doesnt show up array... =/ i dont get how function get variable array from other function...

Comment: What you want to do? $array in the first function is meaningless - the <code>$array(...);</code> actually calls the function by name which is in the $array variable - but the variable is not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Two things

`$myvar` is not used anywhere in your functions;

you should learn how to add element in declared array.

```
    function first()
    {
        global $myvar;        
        $myvar=array('apple','banana','orange');
    }
```

Comment: then what if use with $myvar = explode(";", $line)?

Comment: @user: What is `$line` where it is come from?

Comment: i only give example... $line = "apple;banana;orange;"; because im in troublesome with php read and write file.. i see function cant read array from global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting variable `$array` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`$array` isn't in the scope of function 2.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use global variables just because you are lazy. Use return values and function parameters instead

```
function first () { return array('apple','banana', 'orange'); }
function second ($param) { print_r($param); }
$fruit = first();
second($fruit);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the variable `$myvar` in the `global $myvar;` line, but then you are trying to use a variable called `$array`.

Try using the lines:

```
$myvar = array('apple','banana','orange');
```

and

```
print_r($myvar);
```

Answer (score -1):

i thing the right code it look like this:

```
$myvar = array();

first();
second();

function first(){
    global $myvar;
    array_push($myvar, 'apple', 'banana', 'orange');
}
function second(){
    global $myvar;
    print_r($myvar);
}
```

array_push add new items to the array.

Answer (score -4):

Try this with using a class instead of two functions with one global variable:

```
class functions {

    $myvar = array();

    function first(){
        $this->myvar = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
    }

    function second(){
        print_r($this->myvar);
    }
}

$fn = new functions();

$fn->first();
$fn->second();
```

It is not a good idea to use global vars (as you did in your question).

Comment: ... persisting bulletin board grammar and giving irrelevant advises instead of an explanation that's useful to OP.

Comment: @mario, what do you mean `bulletin board grammar`? and my advise is not irrelevant, it is not a good idea to use global vars, it can get hanky

Comment: Use proper capitalization. The silly globals are evil meme is not overly helpful in a shallow one-liner. And rewriting two simple functions into an object does _not_ explain what OP stumbled upon.

Comment: @mario there is **NO** rule on SO about grammar, if you would like to show it to me i'd gladly read it.

Comment: There is no rule. But it's allowed to downvote answers for any reason whatsoever. And yours always look like you mistake SO for a bulletin board.

Comment: @mario, downvoting should be for a particular reason, like the answer is incorrect or the like, not due to grammar and capilization.

Comment: I'm willing to overlook your low quality writing style (the downvote is silly, since  you are unwilling to change it anyway). But like I told you, the advise is still not useful. Also there is really no point in always inquiring about the downvotes when you're not listening anyway.

Comment: I have edited this answer thoroughly, so I think the downvotes can be removed!

Comment: @Markus. i like my orig answer. i think i might rollback and fix the capitalization

Comment: @markus I have to agree with Neal on this one. Totally changing other people posts and "putting words in their mouth" is bad practice IMO and should be avoided.